# Performance Issue while adding number(>50) of panels in IE11 EXTJS 4.2.1

Tags: extjs

Have a requirement where I need to add the panels dynamically when user selects Select All from the grid. Once user clicks on Select All I am selecting the records one by one in the grid and adding the panels. But if the number of records reaches >50 it is hanging in IE11. I know that panel is heavy compared to other components. But I need to provide close option for each and every individual panel. The panel contains a text input and few check boxes. In Chrome it is working fine. Does IE 11 have any performance issues with EXT JS 4.2.1? Please suggest how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [IE11 Javscript profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to figure out which script takes a long time to execute.

You can single out on which side the slow script stands and, if on ExtJS side, then you could open a bug report.

If the bug stands on your side you can try to revise your strategy about which you select records and open panels.